Windows 10 File Explorer navigation pane only shows quick access
I'm having what looks like two linked problems, one with Quick Access enabled and a liter version with it disabled.
When I open File Explorer and I have Quick Access enabled, it very often shows the green loading bar across the path and nothing in the main section of the window. The navigation pane on the left will show "Quick access" and This PC, but nothing below them... no files, folders, or drives. If I open a second copy of File Explorer on top of the first one, the second one works fine. This happens when opening local files and folder or links to network drives. If I type the network drive of the local drive (X: or C:, etc) into the address field, File Explorer also works fine. Hovering my mouse over the main field of the window shows just the pointer, but when I hove the mouse over the Navigation pane, I get the mouse and the spinning blue circle. After a long time, the Navigation Pane will often populate, but not always.
If I go into File Explorer options and disable both options under Privacy plus Clear the history, File Explorer works better for a couple minutes before doing the same thing again.

I have rebooted several times. I have tried multiple SFCs until there's nothing left to fix.
I have tried DISM with restore health.
I have cleared out both AppData folders for Quick access (%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations and CustomDestinations)
I have rebuilt the Indexer and made sure it doesn't point to anything strange.
I have deleted QATItems from Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Ribbon

This is happening to three PCs in my environment and started out of the blue. Different patch levels, same OS version, similar hardware. Anyone seen this before or have a permanent solution? I don't want to have to wait until we move to Windows11 late this year.

Hey made an account to chime in on this issue. The fix so far for me has been opening up file explorer that second time when it loads. Then click view and then select options. Changing opening File Explorer to "This PC" instead of Quick Access has worked so far. Also only experienced this issue suddenly this week and client has no updates installed since 22H2
